# Calculate length of photographed object given known width

Tags: geometry, angle, rectangles

Sorry, I feel like this should be simple, but I'm stumped and I've searched everywhere.  Is it possible to calculate the length of a photographed object in the attached scenario if you know the width and assume it is a perfect rectangle?

[image: pic of flat rectangle from angle]

Comment: Is the rectangle in an horizontal plane ? Is the image centered on the optical axis ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to know more parameters.

Imagine you're raytracing the rectangle, your viewplane has a certain x, y size value. In general y / x == WINY / WINX. WINY and WINX being the size of your window in pixels.

Image explaining the very basics of raytracing in case you don't know about it : 
[image: basic explanation]
So the eye is your camera, the viewplane is where you cast the image (so the rectangle will appear as in your image here(trapezoid)).
You cast rays to the viewplane to see if they hit an object, if they do, you display the color of the hit object on the viewplane.
Imagine a sheet of paper behind the viewplane, that is your photographied rectangle and when one of the red lines(rays) hit that sheet then it is displayed on the viewplane.
When you have casted enough rays to get a sufficient resolution, you display the viewplane, and then you have your image.

Now imagine you reduce y(viewplane height) but let x, WINY and WINX the same value, the apparent size of l will change but the apparent size of foreground and background w won't change.

I guess you need to know more about the camera specifications

Answer (score 0):

I take $l$ and $w$ to be the measured length and width of the unphotographed rectangle. The length (height) of the photo-rectangle (trapezoid) is the perpendicular distance between the lower and upper bases of the trapezoid. Multiply that by the ratio of the measured lower base to the measured upper base to get the corrected length of the photo-rectangle, i.e. the length its image would have if the photo were taken with all parts of the object at a distance from the camera equal to that of the lower base. Then get $l$ by multiplying the corrected photo-length by the ratio of the rectangle's true width to the measured lower base in the photo, its "true" photo-width.

Comment: This trapezoid is projectively equivalent to *every* rectangle. Even having fixed the source rectangle’s width, for any length there is a projective camera that will produce exactly the same trapezoid. It doesn’t seem possible to recover and unknown length with only the information given.

Comment: @amd-Looks like I have more to learn here. Is "projective camera" a term of art, i.e. not just any camera? What more must OP know to calculate the length?

Comment: Essentially, its a camera that creates an image by projecting rays from some point and intersecting them with a plane. This is an ideal camera that ignores lens distortion and other stuff, and is a widely-used approximation to a real camera. A pinhole camera is a useful physical model for this. Placing the camera “at infinity” gets you various parallel projections.

Comment: Even with a fixed-width rectangle, as the rectangle being imaged gets longer, the camera can be moved farther back and down to compensate and maintain the same trapezoidal image, so without having some other point of reference or information about the camera, there’s no way to recover the rectangle’s height. Mathematically, given two convex quadrilaterals, there’s a projective transformation that maps one onto the other. In particular, this means that a given trapezoid is projectively equivalent to *all* rectangles.

Comment: Thanks, I'm persuaded. You remind me of a photo I took of one end of the Parthenon, from close in on the right looking up.  Ignoring the pediment, the image viewed as you normally view a photo is a quadrilateral, neither rectangular nor trapezoidal, but more distorted than I recall it appearing when I viewed it .  But when I move my eye up close to the lower right corner of the photo, the structure gradually assumes the more nearly trapezoid shape it presented when the photo was taken.  (I ignore that the structure is indeed slightly trapezoidal due to the entasis of its columns.)

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the rectangle to be horizontal (and the picture vertical) at relative height $z$ of the optical axis and distance $d$ of the viewing plane, the coordinates of the two right corners in the image are given by

$$\left(\frac{fw}{2d},-\frac{fz}{d}\right),\left(\frac{fw}{2(d+l)},-\frac{fz}{d+l}\right)$$ where $f$ is the focal length.

If $f$ is unknown, you only have access to the ratio $\dfrac lf$.